# Timestamp in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-mega

```
int sensorArray[32] ;
int selectPinZero = 8;
int selectPinOne = 9;
int selectPinTwo = 10;
int selectpinthree=11;
int Enablepin=7;

int inputPinOne = 0;
int inputPinTwo = 1;



int sensor1;
int sensor2;
int voltage1;
int voltage2;
int Current_Sensor1[16];
int Current_Sensor2[16];
int row;
int column;

int array[17][5]={
                    {0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,1},
                    {0,0,0,1,0},  
                    {0,0,0,1,1},
                    {0,0,1,0,0},
                    {0,0,1,0,1},
                    {0,0,1,1,0},
                    {0,0,1,1,1},
                    {0,1,0,0,0},
                    {0,1,0,0,1 },
                    {0,1,0,1,0},
                    {0,1,0,1,1},
                    {0,1,1,0,0 },
                    {0,1,1,0,1},
                    {0,1,1,1,0 },
                    {0,1,1,1,1}, 
                    {1,0,0,0,0} 
                 };


unsigned long StopTime=0;
int Counter=0;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(selectPinZero, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(selectPinOne, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(selectPinTwo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(selectpinthree,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(inputPinOne, INPUT);
  pinMode(inputPinTwo, INPUT);
}


void loop()
{

  for(row=0;row<17;row++)
  {

    digitalWrite(Enablepin,array[row][0]);
    digitalWrite(selectPinZero,array[row][1]);
    digitalWrite(selectPinOne,array[row][2]);
    digitalWrite(selectPinTwo,array[row][3]);  
    digitalWrite(selectpinthree,array[row][4]);  
    sensor1=analogRead(inputPinOne);
    sensor2=analogRead(inputPinTwo);
    voltage1=sensor1 * ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING;
    voltage2=sensor2* ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING;
    Current_Sensor1[row]=(10*voltage1)-25;
    Current_Sensor2[row]=(10*voltage2)-25;
    Serial.print("Currentsensor1:");
    Serial.println( Current_Sensor1[row]);
    Serial.print("Currentsensor2:");
    Serial.println( Current_Sensor2[row]);
     Counter=Counter+1;
    Serial.print("Counter:");
    Serial.println(Counter);
    Serial.println(".......................");
        delay(1000);


     }
}
```

Here is my Arduino code. I wanted to activate Digital pin for every 1000ms delay.

During each delay the analog value should be stored in an array of index.

I don't know how to keep track of analog value read, or from which port I am reading. I could flicker the LED on the hardware side but it doesn't make any sense. Any method you can suggest here?

Application:

I have 32 hall sensors connected via mux circuit. I wanted to know which sensor is reading value. I want any idea to might suggest to me to keep track here.

Answer (score 1):

You should download timer1 library from http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1

Init timer1 with a value of 1000000 and it will perform an overflow every second. On every overflow it will perform an action, put your code to activate a pin there. And do the serial readings in your loop.